# OpenFileDialog in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, dialog, label

How can I get the result (meaning the file name and its location) from an Open File Dialog?

My code:

```
private void selectFileButton_Click( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
    var selectedFile = selectFileDialog.ShowDialog();
    //label name = fileName
    fileName.Text = //the result from selectedFileDialog
}
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: I don't know how to get the selected file's name and location from the dialog

Comment: Have you looked at the `FileDialog` object's properties?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
private void selectFileButton_Click( object sender, EventArgs e ) 
{
    Stream fileStream = null;
    //Update - remove parenthesis
    if (selectFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && (fileStream = selectFileDialog.OpenFile()) != null)
    {
        string fileName = selectFileDialog.FileName;
        using (fileStream)
        {
           // TODO
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The OpenFileDialog class has a FileName property for that.

Typically, you want to make sure the user didn't cancel the dialog:

```
using (var selectFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog()) {
  if (selectFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
    fileName.Text = selectFileDialog.FileName;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(selectFileDialog.ShowDialog())
{
  // use the methods and properties on selectFileDialog
  fileName.Text = selectFileDialog.FileName; // Assumes only one file was selected
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
if(selectFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
        var result = selectFileDialog.FileName; 

        if((myStream = selectFileDialog.OpenFile())!= null)
        {
            // Insert code to read the stream here.
            ..........
            myStream.Close();
        }
    }
```